# Why is the floated element overlapping the element below and not the other way round?

Tags: html, css, css-float

```css
div {
  background-color: #00FFFF;

}
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;

}

#p1 {
  background-color: red;
float: left;


}
#p2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#p3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
#p4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

#s1 {
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
}

#s2 {
  top: 2px;
 left: 2px;

}
#s3 {
  top: 3px;
 left: 3px;

}
#s4 {
  top: 4px;
 left: 4px;

}
```

```html
<h1>Floating Elements</h1>

<div>
  <p id="p1"><span id="s1">A</span></p>
  <p id="p2"><span id="s2">B</span></p>
  <p id="p3"><span id="s3">C</span></p>
  <p id="p4"><span id="s4">D</span></p>
  <section>This is regular content continuing after the the paragraph boxes.</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why so ?

Because that is how float works.

When you are putting `float` on an element, you are not actually saying much about how that element itself should displayed - but rather how/that the following content should flow around it.

To be more precise, the following *inline* content.

Since your paragraphs are block elements, and you have also fixed their width and height to 50px, this is the result you get - the inline content of the `#p2` paragraph *does* flow around the `#p1` paragraph; but width and height restrictions of the parent paragraph don't allow that parent to grow accordingly.

---

Edit:
If you're having trouble understanding what I am trying to say, consider the following simpler example:

```css
#floated {
  float:left;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border:1px solid red;
}

#unfloated {
  border:1px solid blue;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="floated"></div>

<div id="unfloated">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
```

As you can easily see, without a background for the floated element, the second, non-floated div element stretches across the whole width, "under" the floated element, and *only* its inline content, the Lorem Ipsum text, floats around the floated element.

*That* is how float works.

In your example, you see the "B" show up in the second square - *because* the parent block element of that B is limited to 50px in width and height, so it can not grow to encompass the "B", the "B" text simply flows out of its parent element dimensions as is standard with the default `overflow:visible`.

Comment: I am confused. I don't have an image in my code above. And there is not parent paragraph which has a child paragraph. Can you please clarify ?

Comment: Sorry, image was my bad. Replaced by element ids for clarification. And by parent paragraph I mean the paragraph around the span and its text content - only that span and its text are the _inline_ content that gets floated around the first element. The `#p2` element is laid out "under" the floated element - again, remove the width restriction on that particular element, then it should become clear.

Comment: Check my edit with additional, simplified example, that should make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

From MDN's [Stacking and float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_and_float)

> For floating blocks the stacking order is a bit different. Floating blocks are placed between non-positioned blocks and positioned blocks

And it goes on further to say

> If the opacity of the non-positioned block (`#p2` in your example) is reduced, then something strange happens: the background and border of that block pops up above the floating blocks, but still under positioned blocks.

Comment: Sorry but my question is not how to get #p2 on top of #p1.

Comment: @abc sorry about that, sometimes folks just want a solution when they ask "why" so I figured I would offer one. I didn't understand why at the time, but I dug into it and TIL the stacking order of a floated element is in between non-positioned and positioned elements, unless the non-positioned element has a non-`1` `opacity`. If you add `#p2 { opacity: .99; }`, then `#p2` will appear on top of `#p1`. Or obviously you can give it a `position`, per my previous answer that was downvoted. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `clear-fix` after floated elements, something like:

> Elements after a floating element will flow around it. To avoid this,
>   use the clear property.

[CSS Layout - float and clear](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp)

```css
div {
  background-color: #00FFFF;

}
p {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px;

}

#p1 {
  background-color: red;
float: left;


}
#p2 {
  background-color: green;
}
#p3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
#p4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

span {
  position: relative;
}

#s1 {
 top: 1px;
 left: 1px;
}

#s2 {
  top: 2px;
 left: 2px;

}
#s3 {
  top: 3px;
 left: 3px;

}
#s4 {
  top: 4px;
 left: 4px;

}

.clear { clear:both; }
```

```html
<h1>Floating Elements</h1>

<div>
  <p id="p1"><span id="s1">A</span></p>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p id="p2"><span id="s2">B</span></p>
  <p id="p3"><span id="s3">C</span></p>
  <p id="p4"><span id="s4">D</span></p>
  <section>This is regular content continuing after the the paragraph boxes.</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lose the float: left; on #p1{}, add a position:relative; to your div{} and position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; to your #p2{}. Not sure what you're trying to achieve but if you rather keep the float: left; on #p1{} than you need to clear: both; on p{}.